# Maven jar compiling

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-3, maven-dependency-plugin

I have two projects in my Eclipse A and B, A depends on B, so I added a section of ... to A's POM.xml. Locally, it works fine. I can run A which uses classes from B. However, In my Jenkins continuous build, it fails due to not being able to find the jar file for project B.

I guess maybe there is no jar produced for project B, and I checked .m2 directory, it doesn't exist. How can I make it work for Jenkins's build for dependencies?

Comment: Do for the first project a `mvn install` which installs the created jar into the local repository `$HOME/.m2/repository` which can be consumed by the second one.

Comment: @khmarbaise, tried "mvn install" in the first project, but it says "Could not find artifact de.dfki.mary:marytts-client:jar:5.2-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
". But why I can execute in Eclipse?

Comment: It is possible to configure Jenkins in a way that each project uses an isolated maven repository. Is this the case? Have you considered a Maven multi-module project? As an intermediate step I would try to build the projects manually with Maven (outside eclipse).

Comment: @Gustave, you are right.